# How set my app id of Telegram in tdesktop?

Tags: c++, telegram

I got the app api_id and app api_hash from the Telegram app page, and I set them into config.h, then build and run the App, but it can not connect to the server. Is there a document to tell us how to set.

Comment: Error message please

Answer (score 0):

The logs as below:
[10:03:33.390 02-0000124] MTP Info: connection through IPv4 succeed. (connection.cpp : 2294)
[10:03:33.390 02-0000125] AuthKey Info: Connection updating key from Session, dc 3 (connection.cpp : 2346)
[10:03:33.391 02-0000126] AuthKey Info: Connection update key from Session, dc 3 result: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 (connection.cpp : 2363)
[10:03:33.391 02-0000127] AuthKey Info: No key in updateAuthKey(), will be creating auth_key (connection.cpp : 2368)
[10:03:33.391 02-0000128] AuthKey Info: sending Req_pq... (connection.cpp : 2394)
[10:03:33.391 02-0000129] AuthKey Info: sending request, size: 5, num: 0, time: 1523930613 (connection.cpp : 2906)
[10:03:33.436 03-0000131] Connection Info: sending fake req_pq through TCP/IPv4 transport (connection_auto.cpp : 57)
[10:03:33.441 03-0000135] Connection Info: HTTP/IPv4-transport chosen by tcp error, ready (connection_auto.cpp : 317)
[10:03:33.441 03-0000136] MTP Info: connection through IPv4 succeed. (connection.cpp : 2294)
[10:03:33.441 03-0000137] AuthKey Info: Connection updating key from Session, dc 2560002 (connection.cpp : 2346)
[10:03:33.441 03-0000138] AuthKey Info: Connection update key from Session, dc 2560002 result: E2 FB 19 10 76 66 A6 F5 (connection.cpp : 2363)
[10:03:33.444 03-0000139] MTP Info: sending ping, ping_id: 18200562258533656710 (connection.cpp : 698)
[10:03:33.448 03-0000141] MTP Info: sending request, size: 22, num: -1601224192, time: 1523930613 (connection.cpp : 3021)
[10:03:33.632 02-0000144] AuthKey Info: receiving Req_pq answer... (connection.cpp : 2407)
[10:03:33.634 02-0000145] MTP Info: response in 241ms, _waitForReceived: 4000ms (connection.cpp : 1137)
[10:03:33.782 03-0000147] MTP Info: response in 332ms, _waitForReceived: 4000ms (connection.cpp : 1137)
[10:03:33.782 03-0000149] MTP Info: other salt received... received: 17995337670590168221, my salt: 0, updating... (connection.cpp : 1393)
[10:03:33.782 03-0000151] Message Info: bad server salt received (error_code 48) for msg_id = 6545232146901975552, seq_no = 1, new salt: 17995337670590168221 (connection.cpp : 1660)
[10:03:33.782 03-0000152] MTP Info: setting client unixtime to 1523930615 (utils.cpp : 103)

[10:03:33.805 02-0000165] AuthKey Info: sending Req_DH_params... (connection.cpp : 2453)
[10:03:33.805 02-0000166] AuthKey Info: sending request, size: 80, num: 0, time: 1523930616 (connection.cpp : 2906)
[10:03:33.842 02-0000168] HTTP Error: protocol error 302 - Error transferring http://149.154.175.100:80/api - server replied: Bad Request